# bootstrap navbar search in other jade file

Tags: angularjs, pug

in my Angular JS application, in view folder, in layout.jade file I use bootstrap "nav.navbar.navbar-inverse" from "http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-navbar.php" and I did one change in the following line.
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search')
to 
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Search' ng-model='searchText')
Then, I use another jade file vieworder.jade, here is the content

```
extends layout
block content
table.table.table-striped(ng-app="vieworder", ng-controller="viewordercontroller" border='1', cellpadding='7', cellspacing='7')
thead
tr
 th(width="10%") Customer Name
 th(width="10%") Order Type
 th(width="10%") Orders 
 th(width="10%") Order Date
 th(width="10%") Order Status
 td(width="10%")  
tbody
 tr(ng-repeat='Order in Orders | filter:layout.searchText')
   td {{ Order.custname }}
   td {{ Order.ordertype }}
   td {{ Order.noorder }}
   td {{ Order.orderdate }}
   td {{ Order.orderdate }}
   td
      a.btn.btn-small.btn-primary(ng-click='cancelOrder(Order.id)') cancel
```

Now, when I run, I got all the order list in my vieworder page, which is working perfectly. Now I want to apply filter to the table content. For that I use 'searchText' ng-model. But when I type any alphabet to the search field, filter is not working. Please help me..

Here is the controller code

```
var order = angular.module('vieworder', []);
order.controller('viewordercontroller', function ($scope, $http, $window){

$http.get('/viewalloders').
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available
    $scope.Orders = data;
    console.log(data);

}).
  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log("error");
});
console.log("santanu");

$scope.cancelOrder = function (id) {
    var path = '/deleteorder/' + id;
    var input = [];
    input.id = id;
    $http.put(path, input).success(function (response) {
        console.log("success"); // Getting Success Response in Callback
    }).
        error(function (response) {
        console.log("Santanu :error"); // Getting Error Response in Callback
    });
 }
});
```

Comment: Why layout.searchText? Try searchText only. Also what about the controller.Do both share the same controller.

Comment: I tried with searchText only. It is not working. I have share the controller code

Comment: I am creating the jsFiddle. In the mean time, your code ng-repeat='Order in Order where your controller has $scope.Orders. If this is the case, your data will not be displayed. Can you confirm your code again. For sure it is not layout.searchText

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/6uk006fj/2/

Comment: Yes. This is my contoller, that I have mentioned above.

Comment: Then your jade is wrong.  How you get output? tr(ng-repeat='Order in Orders | filter:layout.searchText') is correct. not tr(ng-repeat='Order in Order | filter:layout.searchText')

Comment: Yes. it will be Orders. But filter is not working.

Comment: Can you compare your code with my jsFiddle and let me know. Can we see the navbar code.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with state based routing and it still works. http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/6uk006fj/3/

Comment: thanks Alaksandar Jesus Gene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using same controller for both the views, then you don't need to use **layout.searchText**. Simply, use searchText since $scope is shared across entire controller. You can directly access it.

If you are using a different controller for both the views, then $scope is different for both the views. In that case you can define your searchText something like:

In your Navbar controller:

```
$scope.object = {};
$scope.object.SearchText = "someVal";
```

and then use this as "Order in Orders | filter:'object.searchText'" in your viewOrderController.

Let me know if this doesn't work

Thanks